# I m trying to change to field with $set in mongoose but only one field change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
Packages.findOneAndUpdate(
{filter},
{$set:{$inc:{reviews:1}},
       rating:4},
{new:true,
 upsert:true,
 multi:true}, 
 function(err, found){
     if(!err){
       console.log("updated")
     }else{
       console.log(err)
     }
   })
```

Only rating is getting changed and reviews is not incremented at all.
Both reviews and rating is of same type i.e Number.

And I'm getting "updated" message in console.

Answer (score 3):

Apply `$inc` without `$set`:

```js
Packages.findOneAndUpdate({filter}, {
  $set: { rating: 4 },
  $inc: { reviews: 1 }
}, {
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
  multi: true
});
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j17F2PKyhXZ)